# Give an example of a vector space $V$ and a lineaar transformation $T:V \to V$ which does not have a non-zero eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Give an example of a vector space $V$ and a lineaar transformation $T:V \to V$ which does not have a non-zero eigenvector.

I know that if $V$ is finite dimensional and T is bounded then it has a non-zero eigenvector but I can't construct an example which doesn't have a non-zero eigenvector.

Comment: By definition, eigenvectors are non-zero.

Answer (score 4):

Let $V$ be the space of all polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb R$, and $T:p(x)\mapsto xp(x).$

Answer (score 4):

There are two things that you can play with:

1. Using a non-algebraically closed field. In this case you can take the matrix $[[0,1],[1,0]]$ over the reals(!). It will have characteristic polynomial $x^2+1$ which doesn't have real roots. Therefore, no eigenvectors.
2. Go to the infinite dimensional case. You can use, $S:\ell^2\to \ell^2$ defined by $S(x_0,x_1,...)=(0,x_0,x_1,...)$

Answer (score 2):

In the plane an eigenvector $v$ leads to a line  $L$ (1-dimensional subspace) such that $T(L) = L$.  Any rotation around the origin  by angles${}\neq0,\pi$ will move any line to a different line. So they all have no eigenvectors.